# "xxxx it is then!", what does it really mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Every now and then, I hear others say "xxxx it is then", e.g. "10:30am it is then", "$200 it is then", I myself sometimes say this too, as a means to confirm some arrangement I suspect I did not hear correctly.

Is confirmation actually the supposed use of such expressions?

Comment: It is a confirmation of an agreed-upon time, amount, or something else. Here it is pizza: "A: What should we get for dinner?" "B: How about pizza?" "A: Pizza it is, then!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a summation that confirms an agreed-upon time, amount, or other article of negotiation.

In the following it is pizza:

> **A**: What should we get for dinner?
>   **B**: How about pizza?
>   **A**: Pizza it is, then!

(**A** is probably going to pick up the phone and place an order at this point.)

Comment: Thank you! I marked this as Answer, pity I cannot vote up!

Answer (score 0):

We use 'it is then' in context with our totally corroboration.
for instance:
A:Where will we go, India or pakistan?
B:I think we should go India.
A:Okay, India it is, then.

here B decides to go India and A confirms it.By saying it is then,A also directs that we definitly go where you said.now B has no right to change the place.

Comment: Hi, dr. ravi. Welcome to English Language and Usage. I don't see much difference between your answer and Robusto's answer. Please refrain from posting the same answer as it is not a discussion forum. . Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance